# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < --> jsonp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsonp

```
 jsonp = (url, callback) => {
        var callbackName = 'jsonp_callback_' + Math.round(100000 * Math.random());
        window[callbackName] = function(data) {
            delete window[callbackName];
            document.body.removeChild(script);
            callback(data);
        };

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + 'callback=' + callbackName;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

componentDidMount() {
 this.jsonp('https://www.naver.com');
}
```

i want a xml data. but Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < error occurs...
how should i do?
help me.

Comment: i want to get a xml data...

Comment: .. and put it to a script tag?

Comment: no! just get a xml data.
i need the og data..
meta tag...

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippet then.

Comment: example:
<meta property="og:title" content="네이버">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.naver.com/">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://s.pstatic.net/static/www/mobile/edit/2016/0705/mobile_212852414260.png">
<meta property="og:description" content="네이버 메인에서 다양한 정보와 유용한 컨텐츠를 만나 보세요"/>

this data!!

Comment: of course you will get an error, because your data is not valid `text/javascript` type

Comment: so the jsonp can't get the xml data???
then how can get the xml data in external website???...

Comment: @주영이 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP. No XML.